# capture first part of the url

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I've following URLs.

```
/product
/product/1
/product/1/buy

/customer
/customer/1
/customer1/contact
```

I'm trying for a regular expression to get the following match so I can run a switch statement on it.

```
/product

/customer
```

I've tried the following and trying other options as well.

```
request.url.match(/^\/(.*)(\/?)/)
```

Comment: Why not use var segments = yoururl.split('/'); and the first would be '/'+segment[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
arr = [
        '/product',
        '/product/1',
        '/product/1/buy',
        '/customer',
        '/customer/1',
        '/customer/1/contact'
      ]

arr.forEach(a=>console.log(a.match(/^\/([^\/]*)/g)[0]));
```

How about this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use split:

```
var result = request.url.split("/")[1]; // result = product
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mrg9k0j/1/)

Comment: Nice and simple - I like it!

Answer (score 0):

You were close! Try this one

```
/^\/(.*?)(\/|$)/
```

E.g.

```
/^\/(.*?)(\/|$)/.exec('/customer'); // ["/customer", "customer", ""]
/^\/(.*?)(\/|$)/.exec('/customer/asd'); // ["/customer/", "customer"]
/^\/(.*?)(\/|$)/.exec('/customer/asd/asd'); // ["/customer/", "customer", "/"]
```

**Why**
The `^\/` will match the start of the string.
The `(.*?)` will match anything after (including `/`, `?` makes it non-greedy).
The final `\/` will make the regex backtrack until `/` is found after the `(.*?)` or if the end of the string is found `$`.

Comment: it's giving `null` for `/product` or `/customer`

Comment: Stuff a / at the end of the string to compensate for that case.  An extra / won't hurt if there is one there already.

Comment: @kd4ttc also true

Comment: Oh, @Cᴀʟʟᴏᴅᴀᴄɪᴛʏ just fixed this with the $, which is end of line.  Damn, things move fast around here!